# Mass renaming files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple files in one directory in format below where starting date and `.log` (at last) will be same, but in between filenames will be different.

From

```
27_07_2017file1vc001vpxd-1605.log
27_07_2017case2vc001vpxd-9169.log
27_07_2017server3vc001vpxd-4640.log
27_07_2017file24vc001vpxd-9170.log
27_07_2017files5vc001vpxd-4641.log
```

To

```
file1vc001vpxd-1605_27_07_2017_1.log
case2vc001vpxd-9169_27_07_2017_1.log
server3vc001vpxd-4640_27_07_2017_1.log
file24vc001vpxd-9170_27_07_2017_1.log
files5vc001vp-4641_27_07_2017_1.log
```

I have few files with different.  Please treat above filenames as file1, file2, file3, file4, case1, case2, number1, number2...and so on. The word "file" is not fixed in all filename format means - it should renamed as filename_date_1.log. In other words, it should cut middle name which is after date and keep first and date middle and so on

Please do not to suggest using `rename` and `sed` command, since `rename` doesn't work in my Linux server and the organization is not allowing me to use `sed`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages — urgently.  Note that questions asking for 'Urgent help' are not encouraged at all.  You shouldn't include Urgent or synonyms in the description.  And you wouldn't be asking the question if you didn't need help, so requesting help in the title is also tantamount to tautologous.

Comment: Is the trailing `_1.log` fixed for all the file names?  What have you tried?  Which commands are you considering using?  You really should show your best effort, explaining why it isn't working, what it is producing, and what it should be producing — an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Why is your organization not allowing you to use `sed`?  Will it allow you to use Awk, Perl, Python, …?  Why can't you get the Perl-based `prename` command installed?  Why don't you get the file names generated correctly in the first place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run following from inside the directory with the logs.

```
$(ls | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)\.log/mv & \2_\1_1.log/')
```

i.e.

```
$> ls
27_07_2017file1vc001vpxd-1605.log
$> $(ls | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)\.log/mv & \2_\1_1.log/')
$> ls
file1vc001vpxd-1605_file1vc001vpxd-1605_1.log
```

EDIT:

A pure bash solution, without using any external tool.

```
for f in $(ls); do [[ $f =~ ([0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4})(.*)\.log ]] && mv $f "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_1.log" ; done
```

It's checking each file name match the given regular expression. If matches, then it performs the `mv` command.

While performing the regex match, it captures two matching groups, as they are needed to be used later.

`([0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4})` captures anything in the format `dd_dd_dddd` into the first group. `(.*)` can capture anything.

So the regex `([0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4})(.*)\.log` matches any filename in the format `dd_dd_dddd<anything here>.log`.

Comment: Thanks,
Can you plz help me using with mv command.
my Org wont allow me to use sed cmd.
I have edited my ques, plz have a look.
Is it possible to cut the date from initial and place in middle followed by _
e.g. 
From
27_07_2017file1vc001vpxd-1605.log    
  27_07_17case2vc001vpxd-9169.log
it should be 
file1vc001vpxd-1605_27_07_2017_1.log   
  case2vc001vpxd-9169_27_07_17_1.log

using "mv" cmd possible ??

Comment: @Nirmal I've updated the answer. This is valid only for your specific format. Note that I've added "_1.log" instead just ".log" as you've shown so in your example.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain your code   ??
looks like it will first put dot after date. to extract the words and placing words in my order..?? Right
What if date format will be 27_07_17  ??

for f in $(ls); do [[ $f =~ (.{10})(.*)\.log ]] && mv $f "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_1.log" ; done

Comment: @Nirmal updated the answer. I was a bit busy, that's why used a quick and dirty regex. However I've updated it as well. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: Many Thanks Anubis...!!
your code looks good, i will try in my server.
My small concern is - Is it possible to put the dot before filename. like  27_07_17filexxx1vc001vxxd-1605.log After placing dot before filename . File looks like 27_07_17.filexxx1vc001vpxd-1605.log   and reorder the word  ??
Reason why i am asking this sometimes the files are getting generated with diff date format. Will your code works at that situation ??

Comment: Change the second argument of `mv` into `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.log`

Comment: Thanks i will try in my server and update on the same

Comment: Hi Anubis,
Thanks ..!! your code help me .
Can you plz help one more query-
How to search the file and move the same file to multiple folders using find cmd ?